# Piped input for `bc` division generates random numbers

Tags: bash, division, bc

I've got two files formatted in this way:

File1:

```
word token occurence
```

File2:

```
token occurence
```

What I want is a third file with this output:

```
word token occurrence1/occurence2
```

This is my code:

```
while read token pos count
do
    #get pos counts
    poscount=$(grep "^$pos" $2 | cut -f 2)
    #calculate probability
    prob=$(echo "scale=5;$count / $poscount" | bc -l)
    #print token, pos-tag & probability
    echo -e "$token\t$pos\t$prob"
done < $1
```

The problem is that my output is something like this:

```
-   :   .25000
:   :   .75000
'   ''  1.00000
0   CD  .00396
1000    CD  .00793
13  CD  .00793
13th    JJ  .00073
36
29
16  CD  .00396
17  CD  .00396
```

There are lines with numbers that I don't know where they come from, they are not in the previous files.

Why do these numbers appear?  Is there a way to remove those lines?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the real file names? Double quote the variables for safety: `"$2"`.

Comment: Why do you not post some lines of the real files? Have you tried to debug your own script using tricks such as `-x` option or `echo -e ">$token<\t>$count<\t>$postcount<"`? In order words, how can you be so sure that it is the division which ``generates you random numbers`` when you have not inspected the `count` and `postcount` values?

Comment: Probably the culprit: `grep "^$pos" $2 | cut -f 2`; if several lines begin with a particular value of `$pos`, then `grep` would find all of them.

Answer (score 0):

1. Method using `paste`, `cut`, & `dc`:

   ```
   echo "5 k $(paste file[12] | cut -f 3,5) / p" | dc | \
   paste file1 - | cut --complement -f 3
   ```
2. Method using `bash`, `paste` & `dc`:

   ```
   paste <(join -1 2 file1 -2 1 file2 -o 1.1,1.2)  \
     <(echo "5 k $(join -1 2 file1 -2 1 file2 -o 1.3,2.2) / p" | dc)
   ```